# Does the new Google OAuth 2 Implementation for Google Apps Marketplace Support Java in addition to Javascript?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

Per this announcement by Google this week: http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2013/11/third-party-apps-now-easier-to-find-and.html Google now supports OAuth 2 for App Marketplace apps, but the examples are all Javascript, we currently have a server side flow and I am wondering if this will still be supported and if there are any examples yet available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Google Apps Marketplace experience fully supports using Java for your server-side authorization flow. You can use the [Google APIs Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) to make authenticated calls like you would for any other Google APIs integration.

We're actively working on improving our documentation so any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds great can I get list of pertinent endpoints and parameters to pass to them? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Any Google service that an admin enables that also has an API will work. There are a lot of Google APIs documented on https://developers.google.com/google-apps/. The [Google APIs Explorer](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/) provides a nice consolidated list and a means to test those APIs right in the browser.