# How to call CustomerLicense: get Method ? What are the Authorization steps With .NET Client Library?

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I have an app on Google Apps Marketplace.
I need to discover, any domain have installed our app or what is the actual status.
For this Google Provide Api function

https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/customerLicense/get

While i go With 2 Legged Authentication It Fails..

So how to Do with C# Client Libraries Or Rest API..

Please Help..

I'm using my project number as application ID...

For Authorization Process I'm using the Following Method

```
public HttpWebRequest GenerateRequest(string contentType, string requestMethod = "GET")
    {
        var ts = UnixTime.ToUnixTime(DateTime.Now);
        var param = new OAuthParameters()
        {
            ConsumerKey = _consumerKey,
            SignatureMethod = SigningProvider.SignatureMethod,
            Version = Constants.Version1_0,
            Nonce = NonceProvider.GenerateNonce(ts),
            Timestamp = ts.ToString()
        };

        //Generate Signature Hash
        var signatureBase = SignatureBase.Create(requestMethod.ToUpper(), _serviceProviderUri, param);
        //Set Signature Hash as one of the OAuth Parameter
        param.Signature = SigningProvider.ComputeSignature(signatureBase, _consumerSecret, null);

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_serviceProviderUri);
        httpWebRequest.Method = requestMethod;
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = contentType;
        httpWebRequest.Timeout = RequestTimeOut;
        //Add the OAuth Parameters to Authorization Header of Request

        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(Constants.AuthorizationHeaderParameter, param.ToHeaderFormat());
        if (requestMethod != "GET")
        {
            String s1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(param);
            var bs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1);
            using (Stream reqStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);
            }
        }
        return httpWebRequest;
    }
```

For Fetching the Response I'm using this one

```
public string GetCustomerLicense(HttpWebRequest req)
    {
        string result = "";
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = req.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            result = resp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var resp = "Message = " + ex.Message;
            result = resp;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The following method I'm using for Calling the CustomerLicence API

```
void CallApi()
    {
        string domainName = "sampledomain.com";
        string clientId = "0000000000";//My projectNumber
        string clientSecret = "MyClientSecret";
        string getCustomerDetails = String.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/customerLicense/{0}/{1}", clientId, domainName);
        GoogleAppsApi gapi = new GoogleAppsApi(getCustomerDetails, clientId, clientSecret);
        HttpWebRequest req = gapi.GenerateRequest("application/json", "GET");
        string result = gapi.GetCustomerLicense(req);
        resultDiv.InnerText = result;
    }
```

Thanks...

Comment: Please post what error are you getting with Oauth. Using project number as application ID is correct. To know what are all the domains who have installed your app, you can use https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/licenseNotification/list, which gives the list of customers for your application. check this link for oauth information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126277/does-the-new-google-oauth-2-implementation-for-google-apps-marketplace-support-j

Comment: I have added the code. What i'm Doing...
and i am getting the following error

{
"error":
{
 "errors":
 [{
  "domain":"global",
  "reason":"authError",
  "message":"Invalid OAuth consumer key",
  "locationType":"header",
  "location":"Authorization"
 }],
 "code":401,
 "message":"Invalid OAuth consumer key"
}
}

Comment: Did you Check the box saying Enable this consumer key in cpanel. Check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/help/articles/2lo-in-tasks-for-admins

Comment: Inside the console.developers.google.com i didn't find this option.  Our application is already Migrated to OAuth 2.0.
If there is something i missed then please Tell me. Thanks

Comment: Hi.. I found http://support.ideascale.com/customer/portal/articles/1302269-google-apps-settings
but i've created my app using my Gmail Account.